# About collective noun

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, collective-nouns

Information, crockery, stationery, luggage are nouns that refers to combination of heterogenous items.
Herd, flock, album, refers to collective nouns with homogenous items.
What is the difference between these two types of nouns in grammar usage?

Comment: In the first case you have nouns that refer to items.  In the second case you have nouns which refer to groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information, crockery, stationery, luggage are uncountable nouns. So they are used with the singular form of a verb and without a/an before them. For example, information is important to the society.

Herd and flock are countable nouns. When they are in the singular form, they can be regarded as either one group or many animals. So they are used with either the singular form or the plural form of a verb. For example, the herd is/are moving forward. But I personally think the singular form of the verb is more frequently used in this case. Some people say a flock of birds/sheep must be used with the singular form of a verb. So if you're not sure, you'd better choose the singular form of the verb.

The word album can only be used with the singular form of a verb.

As for the definite article "the", it can be used before every of the words above if necessary.